# Variance in epigenetic drift rate between different species

Tags: senescence, epigenetics, information

My question relates to the prospect of (near?) future control of biological aging.
As I understand, it has been recently demonstrated by Prof. David Sinclair's group that epigenetic drift appears to be a major driver of aging, and demonstrated it may be reversed by applying a certain subset of Yamanaka factors. In particular, upon fixing DNA aberrations, epigenetic information tends to be restored with less fidelity than the DNA itself. In the mice in the experiment, the degree of epigenetic changes corresponded well to an aged phenotype in these mice, which was also apparently reversed by applying the above said Yamanaka factors.
See https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0092867422015707 for more details..

My question is regarding on the existence of "Horvath clocks" that provide a certain measure of epigenetic drift that can be compared across species. That is, do we have some kind a way to measure more of an "absolute" amount of epigenetic drift, allowing to compare this amount in say, mice, dogs and humans? My hope is that this absolute amount would be much greater in shorter lived species, to an extent providing an approximate explanation to the major differences between the lifespans of these species, to further support Sinclair's theory.

Maybe this measure can not be summarized by a single number, even, but rather depend on epigenetic drift in particular DNA regions/presence of certain methylation patterns etc.?

Comment: I am not an expert, but having a clear definition / source cited of what you mean by "epigenetic drift" and "Horvath clocks" would be helpful. E.g. in some organisms [there is no DNA methylation](https://genomebiology.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/gb-2012-13-10-174). What do you do then? Also, my (out of date) recollection was that epigenetic clocks are not uncontroversial as a method of measuring age. Is that really so good of a measure of age? Clarifying and citing sources would again be helpful here.

Comment: The fact that some species have no DNA methylation indeed complicates the picture (so lets focus on mammals). I am not an expert either, just a longevity enthusiast.. Regarding a definition and utility of "epigenetic drift" - this is in a sense part of my question. I know that the amount of change relatively to youthful patters ("Horvath clocks") are problematic for estimating age, especially following some intervention, even inside a given species. My question is whether there is any work trying to explain inter-species lifespan differences by such "drift rate".